# Firebase allowing writes in node if writer's ID in the node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a simple database structure where group members can add another user to the group.
e.g.
User A created group "Coffee Lovers".
Only user A can add people to the group.
User B is now on the group.
This allows B to invite as well.

```
group-members:{
  "-k3ajsdfklje":{ // This is group id
    groupName: "Coffee Lovers",
    members:{
      "kjk2139_erjw92": true,  // This is member A
      "fekjfqlwke,x9q": true   // This is member B
    }
}
users:{ // Users node.
    kjk2139_erjw92:{
       name:"User A"
    },
    fekjfqlwke,x9q:{
       name:"User B"
    },
    jfkdjklfjklern:{
       name:"User C"
    }
}
```

User A ("kjk2139_erjw92") can add anyone to the group.
User B ("fekjfqlwke,x9q") can add anyone to the group.
User C ("jfkdjklfjklern") cannot add anyone to the group.

I'm not sure how I should build the database rules around this.

```
group-members:{
   "$groupId":{
      members:{
        ".read": true, // This list is publically available
        ".write": "user who is trying to write is authenticated and is included in this list"
        // TODO: I don't know how to write this ".write" part!
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: are the users id is same as their auth.uid?

Comment: @Hareesh Yes, they are. Refer to the "users" node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
".write": "data.child(auth.uid).exists()"
```

Comment: Great starting point. Note that this would allow members to also modify (or even wipe) the existing list. You'll probably want to protect against that by putting the rule one level lower, and only allowing additions.

Comment: Worked like a charm! That's amazing! Thanks @Hareesh

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It's actually really cool cause what you just said was my initial implementation. This was just breaking here and there but I know to do it clean now. I will keep that in mind and update that as we update the server side code. Thanks!